# Клонирование и вставка элемента динамически

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть элемент из дом-дерева:

```
<div class="first">
  <a href="#">25</a>
</div>

<div class="second">

</div>
```

И есть скрипт:

```
jQuery('.first>a').clone().prependTo('.second');
```

Ссылка из класса first появляется динамически и принимает разные значения (иногда там просто пусто). Появляется она вообще при помощи PHP, но это не важно.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы скрипт выполнялся каждый раз, как только в элементе first в ссылке произойдут изменения. Как я понимаю, это решается с помощью Ajax, но я в этом пока не силен.

Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Вы уж определитесь что вам нужно - чтоб выполнялся скрипт когда в ссылке будут изменения? Или чтобы ссылка изменялась Ajax'om? Если второе - то недостаточно сведений - а когда она должна меняться?

Comment: И что означает "появляется динамически ... появляется она вообще при помощи PHP"?

Comment: Она должна изменяться динамически, как только значение в ссылке будет меняться, например 25 изменится на 26, 27 и так далее.

Comment: Событие изменения, если не ошибаюсь: $("#id элемента").change(функция)